# android open photos from camera's folder

Tags: android, directory, android-image

I need for my application to open few images. I need to allow to the user to chose from the pictures he tuck and to use in my application. I have 2 questions:

1. How to get the folder where the camera saves the images?
2. There is any control that allows me to select multiple files (something like OpenFile dialog in winform in .Net)?

Comment: Is he taking the pictures with the camera from inside your app, or outside of it? I believe there is an intent you can use to open the camera, take a picture, then return that picture.

Comment: The pictures are already there. I don't need to open the camera, but to use the existing pictures. I need to create a collage of few existing images. I want to identify the folder and to find a way to allow to select multiple files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will launch the system activity or any registered app using the intent action and allow you to pick an image from the gallery (albums, camera photos, etc)

```
....
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, CHOOSE_FILE_RESULT_CODE);
.....



public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // User has picked an image. 
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        //File URI.. 

    }
```

If you would like just the camera images, here is how you can get a list of camera images by filtering them on the bucket name. In this case, you can read the thumbnails and display them in your own activity and ask users to pick.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME
        };
        String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME + " = ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
            "Camera"
        };
        Cursor mImageCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);

        while (mImageCursor.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d("TestActivity", mImageCursor.getString(1) + "    " + mImageCursor.getString(2));

        }
    }
```

Comment: how to open the default camera's folder on ACTION_GET_CONTENT?

Comment: Check my edit to the answer. I dont know if its possible to use Gallery app with the intent action "ACTION_GET_CONTENT" to take it to a specific folder (i.e. bucket, if you think MediaStore). I'll try to find the answer to that.

Comment: i use this code i can select one file only how can i select multiple files