# Reading user photos in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mediastore

Trying to read the list of photos taken by the user and display them in the imageview. For the sake of simplicity, trying to just display one for now. Have this piece of code so far:

```
Cursor cc = this.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,null);
```

which gets me some data in the cursor, cc.getCount() appears to be making sense (goes up by one when I take a picture, etc.). However, I cannot display the contents in the imageView at all, nothing ever shows up.

Iv'e tried this (s_id is the id of the pic from the cursor above, first returned column):

```
Uri u;
u = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + s_id);
im.setImageURI(u);
```

Also tried this:

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(u.getPath());
im.setImageBitmap(b);
```

No worky. Help?

ps. no errors show up anywhere.

Comment: Perhaps, [this will work](http://mobile.dzone.com/news/displaying-images-sd-card)

Comment: +1 to previous comment. the point is you have to use the MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA field. It has the path to an actual image file.

Comment: aaaaand I feel like an idiot. That did the trick, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way you can let the user pick an image and display it in an imageview.

This code will allow the user to look through files to pick an image from the gallery:

```
Intent picture = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
picture.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(picture, YOUR_CODE);
```

Then in the onActivityResult method you can use the data to set the imageview:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    //This is where you can use the data from the previous intent to set the image view
    Uri uri = data.getData();
    im.setImageURI(uri); //where im is your imageview
}
```

Check out this [link for a more detailed answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573731/android-open-photos-from-cameras-folder)